# Selenium Can't find element when using find_element through Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Keep getting `unable to locate element` error message.

The first find element by xpath  was fine, but the second one is giving me a hard time.

Here is my code:

```
import XLUtils
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Chrome_Driver\Chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/e-services/e-services-businesses/payroll-deductions-online-calculator.html")

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[1]/div[7]/p/a[1]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="welcome_button_next"]').click()
```

Comment: You don't want to use XPaths with that many levels or indices because it makes them brittle (more likely to break). A better first locator would be a CSS selector, `a.btn-primary`. For the second locator, don't find by XPath when you have just an ID. Instead use `.find_element_by_id("welcome_button_next").`

Comment: Also, you need to add the relevant HTML to the question. Providing the link is nice but if the HTML changes in the future, the question won't be useful and can't stand on its own.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to wait a bit for the `Next` button to appear.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

e = wait.until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="welcome_button_next"]'))
    )
e.click()
```

Comment: You don't want to wait for presence here and then click. Presence indicates that the element is in the DOM but not necessarily visible or clickable. You instead want to wait for clickable.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **Next** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.btn.btn-primary#welcome_button_next"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='btn btn-primary' and @id="welcome_button_next"]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Instead of "spamming" questions with more answers that are practically exactly the same as existing answers, why don't you help correct other answers that are near perfect?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Really appreciate it!